# Refugee in USA, needs to travel to his country of origin

Tags: usa, asylum

A friend of mine obtained political asylum here in the USA about a year ago. Now due to family circumstances (death in the family) he wishes to visit his native country X, from which he's a refugee. Technically speaking, he doesn't have to go; but it concerns his close family, so there's a very strong sense for him to be there.

Can he travel to his country of origin without jeopardizing his refugee status? I mean, he sought asylum due to conditions that presented threat to his and his immediate family's life and well-being. He's afraid that traveling back, albeit for a short visit and for a family reason, may be viewed as contradicting his reasons for seeking asylum.

Comment: Returning to his country of origin will indeed jeopardize his refugee status, and in exactly the way you describe. Your friend is already on record saying his life is in danger in that country; traveling to that country now proclaims there's no risk, or that the risk is acceptable to him. Either statement refutes his prior claim for asylum, and will most likely cause his asylum status to be revoked. (I'm a retired attorney, and this is presented as a comment not an answer because I have no first—hand experience with this aspect of the US immigration system.)

Comment: @David: Thank you very much for your comment! But I am still curious to estimate how likely is "most likely", and to find out whether there exist any more or less clearly written laws/guidelines/regulations on this.

Comment: Has he become a permanent resident yet? Or is he still in asylee status?

Comment: You're welcome! I've no real-world experience here, so I don't know whether revocation is merely likely or is absolutely certain. If he does return to his country of origin, when he attempts to re-enter the US, they'll know he left and probably know where he went. Given the current political climate, he will not be regarded with compassion. Searching the web for articles about asylum revocation generates a lot of results. How much risk is your friend willing to accept?

Comment: @user102008: Yes, he has become a permanent resident (green card holder).

Comment: @David: Well, he is stricken with grief (I'd rather not go into the details of his family relationships), and we as his friends are concerned that he is not thinking straight. That's why it's hard to say how much risk he is willing to accept. And that's why I am asking this question here. (And honestly, I am not trying to hide myself behind an imaginary friend -- this is actually about a friend.)

Comment: @zipirovich, that's a big challenge: if he's not thinking straight, then by definition he can't make an informed and intelligent assessment about what to do...or not do. I'm glad he has friends looking out for him.

Comment: @zipirovich: Is the situation that was causing him to be afraid of going back to his  country the same as when he got asylum and permanent residency? Or did the situation change after he got permanent residency such that he is no longer afraid of going back now? If the latter, it's possible for his status to not be affected.

Comment: It would really be a good idea to talk to an immigration lawyer before doing something so risky, especially one with experience in asylum law.

Comment: Was his asylum claim guinine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He would be taking a very, very, very big risk.

He has refugee status presumably because being in his own country would be a risk for his life. If he is willing to return to his own country to attend a funeral, then this is obviously a total contradiction to his claims that he made to get refugee status. So trying to return, he might be in for a nasty surprise.

And if he rightfully received refugee status, then returning to his home country is obviously dangerous and it means risking his life.